# Changing to XFCE from default Gnome3 on Kali 2.0

Tags: kali-linux

I tried method below to install XFCE and was expecting the XFCE desktop to pop up during next reboot:

```
apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base xfce4 xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-goodies
```

The XFCE window manager is installed but, however, I see no changes made to the window interface.

How do I resolve this on Kali 2.0 (sana)?

Comment: could anyone kindly answer to this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the command `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`.

Answer (score 4):

At the GUI login prompt, enter the username. Then you'll see next to the password field the option to change the desktop manager.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question was how to switch to XFCE and this answers it, on a login prompt, enter a username and, when entering password, immediately to the left of the `Sign In` button there is a "Settings" gear, click it and select `Xfce Session`. If you want to change the system default, use either the previous answer or `echo xfce4-session > /root/.xsession` should do...

Comment: Because your answer only applies if you are using GDM and not already using a different display manager such as LightDM with Gnome DE.  In that case, your answer would not apply, but the `update-alternatives` method would still work.